# Can't seem to add a sublayer to my UITableViewCell subclass

Tags: ios, calayer

This code is run from within a subclass of UITableViewCell

```
CALayer* greenLayer = [CALayer layer];
greenLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.bounds.size.height);
greenLayer.frame = frame;
[self.backgroundView.layer addSublayer:greenLayer];
```

But nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was another piece of code which caused the problem. I was retrieving the cell incorrectly.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of adding your sublayer to the backgroundView, add it to the cell's `contentView`:

```
[self.contentView.layer addSublayer:greenLayer];
```

Alternately, you could just directly set the `backgroundColor` property of the contentView:

```
self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Comment: Tried that, does not work either. I am not trying to make a green background btw, that's just so I can see the layer.